# Rename non-empty folder

Tags: go

I'm trying to rename non-empty folders using `os.Rename()`. Here is the error:
`directory not empty`. Is there away to force rename the non-empty folders?

```
package main

import (
    "path/filepath"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)
var PATH = "dir/dir/"
/
func main() {
    err := filepath.Walk(PATH, printDir)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func printDir(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if info.IsDir() {
        arr := strings.Split(info.Name(), " ")
        if len(arr) > 1 {
            err := os.Rename(PATH + info.Name(), arr[0] + "_" + arr[1])
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: It sounds like Go might be complaining because there's a nonempty directory where you want to move this directory to, rather than because the directory you're moving is nonempty.

Comment: @user2357112 yes the error is pretty straight forward. thats not what I'm asking.

Comment: What do you want to do with the directory that's in the way? Merge the contents? Delete it and everything inside?

Comment: @user2357112 I want rename non-empty folder. I tried `os.Rename`, it complaints because the folders are not empty. I'm asking if there's a way to rename non-empty folders :3

Comment: @Bun I believe it's not giving you an error because the folder YOU WANT TO RENAME is non-empty, it's giving you an error because the name you want to CHANGE IT TO is an existing non-empty folder. But I could be wrong :P

Comment: @Bun, `os.Rename` has no such limitation. I just verified with `os.Rename("/tmp/nonempty", "/tmp/new")`. Either you're doing something wrong (more likely) or your OS is limiting you (doubt it).

Comment: @AdamSmith the name I want to change to is not existed.

Comment: I'm not sure why. I'm running this on mac os. `os.Rename` doesn't seem to let me rename non empty folders.

Comment: @Bun your problem is not reproducible. Try narrowing the scope and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Instead of this complex directory traversal, try just creating a non-empty directory `foo` and `os.Rename`-ing it to `bar`, where `bar` doesn't already exist, and see if that works. If it does, your problem isn't related to moving non-empty directories.

Comment: Instead of using `os.Rename`, I got it working with `exec.Command` with `mv....still not sure why `os.Rename` is complaining though.

Comment: @Bun I'm sure there's something simple that's gone wrong. I'd strongly suggest you pick this apart and try something simple with `os.Rename`, but I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: @AdamSmith @user161778 You're right. `os.Rename()` actually able to rename non empty folder. For some reasons, the `if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }` exit the program with 1 error code because one of the folder is already renamed every time I run the code. Now I fixed it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by taking out `if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }` in `printDir` function. It terminates with 1 error code because one of the folder is already renamed each time I run the program.

```
// Rename the folder name to format first_last.
// Then delete all files in each folder that are not jpg extension.
package main

import (
    "path/filepath"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

var PATH = "dir/dir/dir"

func main() {
    err := filepath.Walk(PATH, printDir)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func printDir(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if info.IsDir() {
        if !strings.Contains(info.Name(), "_") && len(strings.Split(info.Name(), " ")) > 1 {
            os.Rename(PATH + info.Name(), PATH + strings.Replace(info.Name(), " ", "_", -1))
        }
    }
    if !info.IsDir() {
        fmt.Println(info.Name())
    }
    return nil
}
```